# Express routes unavailable - Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a chat app with auth I have made that Is all up and running. When on Localhost it is all working fine.  I have deployed to Heroku and the sever serves up the html pages as expected but when doing a fetch request for register/login etc I get an error like below.  While running at localhost this doesn't happen and the app works/can log in/connects to mongoDB perfectly fine

```
login.js:15 POST https://infinite-hollows-61306.herokuapp.com/api/login 503 (Service Unavailable)
registerUser @ login.js:15
VM717:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Is there some additional config I may have missed?

Do the fetch routes need changing when the app is hosted on heroku?

Front End fetch request

```
const result = await fetch('/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json())
```

Server side in server.js

```
const auth = require('./auth.js')
app.use('/', auth)
```

Server Side auth.js

```
auth.post('/api/login/', async (req,res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findOne({ username }).lean()
    if (!user) {
        return res.json({ status: 'Errror', error: 'Invalid Username/Password'})
    }
    if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password )){
        const token = jwt.sign({ 
                id: user._id,
                username: user.username 
            }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', data: token, name: user.username })
    } 

    res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Invalid Username/Password' })
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "live-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"Live chat feature\"",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Dan Wisltrop",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

This is a shot of the error

[image]

Comment: The error message says `/api/register`, but you've posted code for `/api/login` - which is it, then? What does the server response say, apart from the status code? Please update the question with more details.

Comment: HI,I have included the error in the post and will edit the routes .  I have multiple routes all set the same way and they return the same error

Comment: Kindly add the error image from the console tab.

Comment: Thank you Fazal, I have edited with a screenshot of the error